# What properties of physical quantities make them Fourier transform pairs?

Tags: fourier-transform

I understand the general notion of Fourier transform. I wanted to know what properties do a particular pair of physically measurable quantities have that such that the Fourier transform of a function of one of those quantities takes us to a function of the other quantity.

For example:

- frequency $\leftrightarrow$ time
- position $\leftrightarrow$ momentum

Comment: I think you should ask it at Physics SE instead.

Comment: [wikipedia?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_variables).

Comment: [Duplicate](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/428105/origin-of-conjugate-variables-in-physical-theories).

Comment: @CosmasZachos This is a good example of where I do not understand how the duplication rules should be applied. The *question* you've identified as a duplicate is indeed essentially the same as this question. However, the *accepted answer* on that question is not great, in my opinion. However, because the other question is a year old and has an accepted answer, it's unlikely that the author will accept a new, better answer. I am reluctant to post answers to questions like that because I don't like having anything but the best answer marked as accepted. What do you think should be done?

Comment: @DanielSank Sounds like a good discussion to have on [Meta](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com). But if, before this one got closed, you happened to post an incredibly awesome answer that was in every way superior to the other linked question, [then the old one could be made a duplicate of this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290126/duplicate-with-wrong-answers).

Comment: @DanielSank That’s why I desisted from initiating closing....